# Arduino Ethernet won't upload program using Arduino IDE on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, arduino

I'm trying to develop for Arduino using a Macbook Air. I purchased an Arduino Ethernet with a POE module. The only inputs are RJ-45 and Power Adapter. I'm using an Apple USB-Ethernet Adapter, a Cat 5e cable, and a 9V 300Ma power adapter. When I launch the IDE, the only ports that show up are 'Bluetooth' ports. The Arduino does have power to it, so I know the board is not entirely DOA. I don't see any support for developing for the Arduino on a Macbook Air or for the Arduino Ethernet. I realize I could have accomplished this with an Arduino Uno + Arduino Shield, but wanted to use POE.

When I run:

```
    ls /dev/tty.*
```

I only get Bluetooth ports Back. This is on 10.7.4.

Does anyone have experience developing for Arduino Ethernet and/or Arduino on a Macbook Air?

Comment: I should also add that I have a 4gb Sd Card FAT formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your board has a serial programming interface.

```
The 6-pin serial programming header is compatible with the USB Serial adapter and also
with the FTDI USB cables or with Sparkfun and Adafruit FTDI-style basic USB-to-serial
breakout boards.
```

As an example you need [one of these](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/718) to program it.